# Sum and Average of a series of numbers inputed to a text field

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, sum, average

I am trying to create an application that calculates the sum and average of numbers that are inputted into a text field separated by spaces.

I am stuck on the part where you have to put in a loop to calculate the sum and avg from the spaced inputs. I have been using console.log to test throughout while I type my code.

Any guidance would be helpful. First time doing javascript.  I have looked at the forms on this website and it seems like all the sum/avg javascript questions arent input text based. That is why I am creating a new question.

HTML and Javascript is Below

```
<body>
<input type="text" id="numberSeries" />
<button id="calculateSumAverage" onclick="calculateSumAverage();">Calculate</button>
<div id="calculationOutput"></div>
</body>
```

Javascript

```
function calculateSumAverage() {

    //grab the input
    var numberSeries = document.getElementById("numberSeries").value;
    //split it using.split(" ")
    var arr = numberSeries.split("  ");

    //set sum var to 0
    var sum = 0;

    //set avg var to 0
    var avg = 0;

    //loop input array and sum
    for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
        sum += arr[i];
    }
    console.log(sum);

    //divded by
    //calculate avg divided by myarray.length

    //output to div
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
// Here is your function:
/*function calculateSumAverage() {
    //grab the input
    var numberSeries = document.getElementById("numberSeries").value;
    //split it using.split(" ")
    var arr = numberSeries.split("  ");
    //set sum var to 0
    var sum = 0;
    //set avg var to 0
    var avg = 0;
    //loop input array and sum
    for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
        sum += arr[i];
    }
    console.log(sum);
    //divded by
    //calculate avg divided by myarray.length
    //output to div
}*/

// Here is a way to do it functionally:

function calculateSumAverage() {
  // This is the string that contains the numbers separated by a space.
  var inputValue = document.getElementById('numberSeries').value;
  
  var values = inputValue.split(' ')
    .map((val) => parseInt(val))
    .filter((val) => !isNaN(val));
    
  var sum = values.reduce((currentVal, nextVal) => currentVal + nextVal, 0);
  
  document.getElementById('calculationOutput').innerHTML = `Average: ${sum / values.length}`;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <input type="text" id="numberSeries" />
  <button id="calculateSumAverage" onclick="calculateSumAverage();">Calculate</button>
  <div id="calculationOutput"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: But all these sideeffects not wrapped inside an IO Monad :see-no-evil:

Comment: @MartinSeeler => I spot the Haskell programmer. On the other hand though, at least I am TRYING to approach things in a functional manner. I miss Lodash when answering these questions. :(

Comment: I saw your effort, that's why I upvoted your answer :-) I know what you're talking about. Also ramda is very nice.

Comment: @MartinSeeler => Agreed. I keep going back and forth on which of them I like more, but it all seems to be very case-dependent. I would rather see functional programming take over the JavaScript world, rather than the influx of OO programming that we seem to be seeing, but that's just my 2c.

Comment: @th3n3wguy thank you for your approach. It is nice to have another way to the answer.  My question is what is the .map((val)?

Comment: @th3n3wguy I also have never seen the format 'Average: ${ / }'; what does the $, {}, and ' do?

Comment: @king_coney => You can read more about the `.map()` function here (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). I also combined it with the Fat Arrow function, which you can read more about here (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

Comment: @king_coney => You can read more about Template Literals (the backtick and ${} notation) at this URL: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: @king_coney => If this solved your problem, can you please accept it as the answer to the question?

Answer (score 1):

You code is fine except `sum += parseInt(arr[i]);` you need to parse each string input to integer

Comment: Yeah after I posted it I read a little more on the parse. I really appreciate the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

`input type="text"` will give a string.Also to split this string ,use `var arr = numberSeries.split("");` , note there is no space between the quotes. To convert each string to number use unary operator.

`sum += +arr[i];` The `plus(+)` sign before `arr[i]` will convert a string to number.Unless you convert to number , the string concatenation will produce like this  `0123...`

```js
function calculateSumAverage() {

  //grab the input
  var numberSeries = document.getElementById("numberSeries").value;
  //split it using.split(" ")
  var arr = numberSeries.split("");

  //set sum var to 0
  var sum = 0;

  //set avg var to 0
  var avg = 0;
  console.log(arr)
  //loop input array and sum
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    sum += +arr[i];
  }
  console.log(sum);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="numberSeries" />
<button id="calculateSumAverage" onclick="calculateSumAverage();">Calculate</button>
<div id="calculationOutput"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you. Yeah after reading your code I saw that the .split("") was not spaced and I spaced it out and it summed the numbers. I did not know that the plus(+) will convert the string to a number that was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```js
function calculateSumAverage() 
{
 var numberSeries = document.getElementById("numberSeries").value;
 var arr = numberSeries.split("");
 var sum = 0;
 var avg = 0;
 for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) 
 {
  sum += parseInt(arr[i]);
 }
}
```